# Find values so that the equality of the cumulative distribution function is satisfied.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with cumulative distribution function:

$$
F_{X}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x<1\\ 
\frac{1}{25} & 1 \leq x <2\\ 
x^2 & 2 \leq x  < \frac{3}{5} \\ 
1 & x \geq \frac{3}{5} 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I want to determine $F_{d}(.)$ discrete cumulative distribution function, $F_{c}(.)$ continous cumulative distribution function and $\alpha$, $\beta$ with $\alpha+\beta=1$ such that:

$$F_{X}(x)=\alpha F_{d}(x)+ \beta F_{c}(x)$$

Apparently, the functions that they can serve are as follows

$$
F_{d}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x<\frac{1}{5}\\ 
\frac{1}{20} & \frac{1}{5} \leq x <\frac{2}{5}\\ 
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \leq x  < \frac{3}{5} \\ 
1 & x \geq \frac{3}{5} 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

And

$$
F_{c}(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 & x<\frac{2}{5}\\ 
5x^2-\frac{4}{5} & \frac{2}{5} \leq x  < \frac{3}{5} \\ 
1 & x \geq \frac{3}{5} 
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

What would be the appropriate values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Now, I don't understand where these functions come from, it seems that they came out magically but I don't think so, is there any procedure that allows me to get to these functions?